# Insert data AJAX using PHP not working using PDO

Tags: php, jquery

How can i add data using AJAX and PHP script?

HTML

```
<form method="POST" >
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter Question:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="question" name="question"></input></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><button name="add-question" id="add-question">+Add Question</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#add-question').click(function (e) {
    var question = $('#question').val();
    var dataString = "question="+question;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add-question.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

});

PHP Script using PDO

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['add-question'])) {
    include 'db.php';
    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $query = "";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO question (name, choices1, choices2, choices3, choices4, answer) VALUES (:name, ':choices1', ':choices2', ':choices3', ':choices4', ':answer')");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $question);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Quiz has been added";
    } else {
        echo "Error adding quiz";
    }
}
```

?>

I also included the jquery file. But i don't know why it doens't work. Thanks for those who will help me.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab of your browser's developer console? Are you sure you're POSTing what you think you're POSTing?

Comment: It's working now thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a POST attribute called "add-question" so this line will fail.

`if (isset($_POST['add-question'])) {`

Change it to

`if (isset($_POST['question'])) {`

Comment: well, the `<button>` does have the  `name="add-question"`

Comment: Wow it's working now i don't know how it happened but i thought isset is to trigger the button add_question if it's click or not. thanks dude mind to share the isset? :) thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, but the form containing that button is not being submitted, it's being handled through a custom handler which doesn't submit "add-question". You could change the .ajax data attribute to use `$('form').serialize()` instead assuming there was only one form on the page. But just checking for `$_POST['question']` will suffice here.

Comment: To explain a little more, the only POST variables being sent by that ajax call are defined within that "data" attribute, so you are only sending "question". In a regular form post, all variables will be sent including the button. You could also change your ajax call to send all variables from the form using the method in my previous comment.

Comment: @Raptor the button does but he uses ajax to do the actual post. The button isn't of type=submit so wouldn't actually submit the form(too lazy to check that actually)